# Adding new keys & values to Associative array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm building a web scraper to check prices... so I have 2 arrays and I'm trying to merge the data into one array. First array is called $results and is like so:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
[id] => 0 
    [myTitle] => Product One text... 
    [myImage] => Some url...
    [myPrice] => My price
) 

[1] => Array ( 
[id] => 1 
    [myTitle] => Product Two text... 
    [myImage] => Some url...
    [myPrice] => My price
 ) 
)
```

And a second array called imaginatively: $results2:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
    [amzId] => 0 
    [amzTitle] => Amazon Product One text... 
    [amzPrice] => Amazon price
) 

[1] => Array ( 
    [amzId] => 1
    [amzTitle] => Amazon Product Two text...
    [amzPrice] => Amazon price
 )  
)
```

I need to add the second arrays keys and values to the first, where the Id and 'amzId' are the same.

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
[id] => 0 
    [myTitle] => Product One text... 
    [myImage] => Some url...
    [myPrice] => My price
    [amzId] => 0 
    [amzTitle] => Amazon Product One text... 
    [amzPrice] => Amazon price
) 

[1] => Array ( 
[id] => 1 
    [myTitle] => Product Two text... 
    [myImage] => Some url...
    [myPrice] => My price
    [amzId] => 1 
    [amzTitle] => Amazon Product Two text... 
    [amzPrice] => Amazon price
 ) 
)
```

I can't figure out how to best do this. Or if I'd be better off adding the new keys and values to original $results array at the foreach loop when I'm getting the data (for the $results2 array), so I wouldn't need a second array?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: just use `for` loop then `array_merge`

Comment: `foreach ($first as &$a) foreach ($second as $b) if ($a['id'] == $b['amzId']) $a += $b` – super primitive one-line in-comment solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this function . .

```
$arr3 = array_merge($arr1,$arr2);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that just adds them on at the end of the array, not add them to each existing set of results.